# How do I pass multiple options for a like statement?

Tags: sql, db2

I have this query

```
Select Model_Number
From Guitar.Fenders
Where Model_number LIKE ('5%' OR '6%')
```

This doesn't work.

I only want the query to return model numbers that begin with 5 or 6.

Comment: `Model_number  >= '5' AND Model_number < '7'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this, one by making use of `LIKE` and the other by making use of `IN` :

`LIKE`

```
Select       Model_Number
From         Guitar.Fenders
Where        Model_number LIKE '5%' OR Model_Number LIKE '6%'
```

`IN`

```
Select       Model_Number
From         Guitar.Fenders
Where        LEFT(Model_number, 1) IN ('5','6')
```

I'd prefer to use the `IN` statement in case the 'conditions' are likely to increase.

If not, you could simplify this by making use of:

```
Select       Model_Number
From         Guitar.Fenders
WHERE        Model_number >= '5' AND Model_number < '7'
```

You can choose any of these three which suits your needs.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Select Model_Number
From Guitar.Fenders
Where (Model_number LIKE '5%' OR Model_number LIKE '6%')

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the easiest way.

```
Select Model_Number
From Guitar.Fenders
Where Model_number LIKE '5%' OR Model_number like '6%'
```

Hope this helps,
MatthewJ

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Regular Expression for this case, something like:

```
^[56].*$
```

And then pass the regular expression using Xquery.